# Javascript not running in order after refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a system for marking messages read/unread by checking if a user is logged in, grabbed the matching user-drug entry, and then using that. It works fine when going from view to view, but sometimes when I refresh, it will run the display code first (having a null dateLastSeen) and THEN run the code that grabs info from the database (checked via debug). Below is the code in the order it is in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // If user isn't logged in, hide submission/ignore drug visits
    // Otherwise, continue to else statement and figure out drug visit stuff
    var userLoggedIn = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["Username"])) + '';
    var dateLastSeen = null;
    if (userLoggedIn == "Guest") {
        $('.expandMessagePost').hide();
    }
    // If they're logged in but no pairing of user/NDC exists, set all messages to unread
    // If they're logged in and have visited the page, compare the date in the DrugVisit entry
    // and compare that to the message dates, and if they're newer, set them to unread
    else {
        $.getJSON("/api/DrugVisit", function (drugVisitsJsonPayload) {
            $(drugVisitsJsonPayload).each(function (i, item) {
                // Page has been visited
                if (item.NDC == '@Model.Item1.NDC' && item.Username == userLoggedIn) {
                    dateLastSeen = item.Date;
                    console.log("Date found!");
                }
            });
        });
    }

    $.getJSON("/api/Message/", function (messagesJsonPayload) {
        $(messagesJsonPayload).each(function (i, item) {
            if (item.NDC == '@Model.Item1.NDC') {
                var badge = "";
                // Check (if user logged in) if unread, update DrugVisit entry
                if (userLoggedIn != "Guest") {
                    if (dateLastSeen != null) {
                        if (item.Date > dateLastSeen) {
                            badge = "[UNREAD] - ";
                            console.log(dateLastSeen + " - " + item.Date);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        badge = "[UNREAD] - ";
                        console.log(dateLastSeen + " - " + "NULL WTF");
                    }
                }
                $("#messageListing").append('<li> \
                                            ' + badge + item.User + ' - ' + formatDateForOutput(item.Date) + ' - ' + item.Text + ' \
                                             </li>');
            }
        }
        );
    }
    );
</script>
```

Is this some sort of race condition? I'm still new to MVC and ASP.net stuff, so I'm not sure what to do here. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand what order you want things to happen in, but you should probably be using the `.complete` function from the getJson call - for example, if you want to do `$.getJSON("/api/DrugVisit"` and THEN, once you have data from that, do `$.getJSON("/api/Message/"`, you should do something like:

```
$.getJSON("/api/DrugVisit", function (drugVisitsJsonPayload) {
   //do stuff
}).complete(function() {
   $.getJSON("/api/Message/", function (messagesJsonPayload) {
     //do more stuff, knowing that the first call is finished
   });
});
```

Comment: That's perfect, I didn't know about that function, thanks so much!